# DOM...Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, dom

When i tried running this code I get this error..I don't know where i went wrong

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at nventaire.test.main(test.java:10)
```

>

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder parser =
                factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);
        Element racine = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nl = racine.getElementsByTagName("joueur");
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {
            Element joueur = (Element) nl.item(i);
            NodeList listedenoms = joueur.getElementsByTagName("nom");
            Element nom = (Element) listedenoms.item(0);
            System.out.println(nom.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
        }
    }
```

thaks

Comment: And if you check args (length, contents, etc), what does it show?

Comment: Did you give any arguments when starting the program?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the stack-trace of the thrown exception.

I assume it relates to the `args` array - it is probably not set with any element and therefore the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` upon access. You should call your application with some arguments so that the `args` array won't be empty and you will be able to access it, like:

```
//Call along with some argument:
java test firstArgument

//Then access
Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);
```

Comment: I have an XML file in the same folder.
I tried with java test test.xml
but I got an error (No such file or folder of this type)

Comment: On which folder you have the `xml` file?

Comment: @user3600078 You should have the XML file living besides the `test.class1` or to use an absolute path.

Comment: I have test.java, test.class  and test.xml in the Same folder...TP5 :D

Comment: @user3600078 You should have `test.class` and the XML file at the same folder.

Comment: @user3600078 And what if you try to use a full path, like: `c:\myFile.xml`

Comment: Debug your application or print the passed argument

Answer (score 0):

You don't have command line arguments. The error is on:

```
Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);
```

Since you don't have command line arguments, `args` is an empty array and `args[0]` does not exist, causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To fix, include an argument when you run your program, or hard code it in.

Include an argument:

```
java [Program Name] [Whatever your argument is]
```

Hard code it in:

```
Document doc = parser.parse("[Whatever your argument is]");
```

Comment: Well you need to include it when you run your program.

Comment: thank you very much but the problem was in my declaration in the XML file.